Are Succah Schach mats bound with glue kosher?
According to this Star-K link, Schach mats are kosher if they are held together with monofilament plastic wire since it is not considered a “Kli” and not Mekabel Tumah (as opposed to binding of multifilament wire). I should think that non-animal glue ( https://utopia.org/guide/what-is-glue-made-of-and-is-it-vegan/ — “The good thing is that it is usually pretty easy to find vegan-friendly glue brands for your personal use: brands including UHU, Weldbond, Gorilla Glue, and Elmer’s Glue have all been found to be suitable for vegans.“) would also not be considered a “Kli” and would therefore be kosher to bind schach mats. I cannot find any literature about this question. Has anyone come across said literature?
